# Add files to a XCode Project via command line

Tags: ios, xcode

I have to add some files as Resources inside an Xcode project via command line because it needs to be created automatically. Now I need to add some files and folders to this project. I saw some solution like xcs (https://github.com/gonzoua/xcs) and pbxedit.rb. The first one gave me a problem because it Couldn't find Xcode.app and the second one I had to implement my clases and instantiate my objects, and I see the both of them allow to create groups but not folders (something that I need)
Is there a better solution?

Comment: No, I had to create my own perl script